Why is usually Tafel extrapolation done and not a fit of the Butler Volmer equation
Good day guys,
I have noticed in many papers and books there is mention of the use of the tafel approximation to determine the charge transfer coefficients and exchange current density.
Where, for large $|\eta|$
$$\eta_{a/c} = \pm \frac{RT}{\alpha_{a/c} F}\bigl[ln(|j|)-ln(j_0)\bigr] $$
Positive for anodic and negative for cathodic.
However, the usage of the linear Tafel extrapolation requires us to arbitrarily choose the region we are fitting.
The tafel linear approximation at large overpotential entails that for large and small overpotentials:
$$j = j_0 \bigl[ exp(\alpha_af\eta)-exp(-\alpha_c f\eta)\bigr]$$
It seems like doing a fit of the BV equation over both the small and large regions is better than doing the linear Tafel fit as the BV fit is done over the entire potential region rather than at an arbitrary region that is considered to be of sufficiently high potential.

Probably, the answer is in your question. It is easier to fit a straight line (a linear least square fit) than working with the full BV equation an a non-linear least square algorithm. Furthermore, not everybody has the software or the programming knowledge to write the fitting routine.

It is fully expected that original expressions fit better than their approximations. But if conditions for an approximation are met, it is often advantage to use it. Like pH of weak acid pH=0.5(pKa - log c)  if  c >> [H+] >> [OH-]

The arbitrary region is not actually all that arbitrary, for a one-electron transfer reaction (the only case where BV holds anyways) you can calculate what potentials you would need for the Tafel region to be valid within x%. For 99% at RT you find you need to be at overpotentials higher than 120 mV.

@Noah a paper by the IUPAC on the definition of charge transfer coefficients states that they are experimental parameters that often may add to non integer values of the form $\frac{n}{\mu}$ where n being the number of electrons transfer and $\mu$ the number of occurrences. The potential region for which exp(x) >> -exp(-x) or vise versa depends on the charge transfer coefficients, which are not often not known.
